# Skype for business Web SDK - Presence / status 'Be right back'

Tags: skype, skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

I'm in the process of integrating the Skype for Business Web SDK in my webapplication.

My question is about status changes (presence).
According to the samples on https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk I am listening to (my) status changes in the following way:

```
client.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.status.changed(function (status) {
    console.log("My new status: " + status);
    // etc...   
});
```

This works and I can update the UI according to the status change.

There is one exception --> status 'Be right back'.
When the status is changed to 'Be right back' (BeRightBack) externally in a Skype client or in the UI of my application, I'm getting back status 'Away'.

When checking in the Dev Tools of Edge, I see the following:

```
POST
{"availability":"BeRightBack"}
```

and

```
GET
{"availability":"BeRightBack","_links":{"self": {"href":"/ucwa/oauth/v1/applications.... etc }},"rel":"presence"}
```

Also when I sign in while being logged into Skype with the 'Be right back' status, the SDK returns status 'Away'.

When running the samples on https://ucwa.skype.com/websdk I get the same result.
I change the status to 'Be right back' and the alert shows I'm 'Away'.

Am I missing something here? Is this expected behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

Running into the same issue: if I log into skype for business (the desktop client) and set the user to `be right back` the value I get from the web sdk is `away`.
Investigating a little bit I noticed that method is present at sdk.js:44553 (with version 1.2.36)

```
/**
* Transform status values from UCWA to values known to jCafe.
* @param {string} s - status value from UCWA
*/
function fixStatus(s) {
    return Person.Status[s] || {
        BeRightBack: Person.Status.Away,
        Idle: Person.Status.Away,
        IdleOnline: Person.Status.Away,
        IdleBusy: Person.Status.Away,
        Unknown: Person.Status.Offline
    }[s] || Person.Status.Offline;
}
```

Right above, you can see the declaration of the Status enum is missing the BRB value, I don't understand why though, especially since the SDK support the BRB value according to [documentation](http://officedev.github.io/skype-docs/Skype/WebSDK/model/api/modules/jcafe.html#onlinestatus)

```
var Status;
(function (Status) {
    Status.Away = 'Away';
    Status.Busy = 'Busy';
    Status.DoNotDisturb = 'DoNotDisturb';
    Status.Offline = 'Offline';
    Status.Online = 'Online';
})(Status = Person.Status || (Person.Status = {}));
```

To me it looks like it's a status they added after creating the SDK and for retro-compatibility reasons they are doing strange things, hard to confirm without having access to the repository though.

Answer (score 0):

By the way, guys, I realized this; mePerson object has two attribute. One of them is `status` and the other attribute is `activity`.

Let me explain difference between two of them. `BeRightBack` is not a status, it is an activity. The status of `BeRightBack` is `Away` and `activity` is `be-right-back`. Same as `OffWork`. If you set the status to `OffWork` you will see `status = Away` and `activity = off-work` . I did not find how I can set `activity`. If you find anything please let me know.

here is code;

```
var stasus = 'BeRightBack' ;     
        window.skypeWebApp.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.activity.changed(function (status) {
// alert('Activity Changed to: ' + status);
console.log('Activity Changed to: ' + window.skypeWebApp.personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.activity);
});
```

Comment: Could you please specify which version of de SDK you are using?
I am using SkypeBootstrap_1.2.36.min.js and activity be-right-back is never returned.

I do see activity off-work which works fine. Funny thing is, the mePerson object's activity attribute returns the string off-work white the person object's activity attribute returns the string Off Work.

I haven't found a way to set activity in the web application.
For status it's personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.status.set(status) but there is no such thing as personsAndGroupsManager.mePerson.activity.set(activity)

Comment: here anounced general usage [link](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/websdk/docs/gettingstarted)
and I tried 1.2.36 and 1.2.15 (general usage). But two of them have same result. And yes `mePerson.activity` is not working. If you find a way, please let me know.